# How to set RadDataForm in insert mode?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

I want to show RadDataForm in insert mode at startup. How to do it?
Is it possible to do in XAML only?

Answer (score 2):

The `RadDataForm` has an `AutoEdit` property which is supposed to set the control in edit mode when it loads, but I've been unable to get that to work. There is an alternative though; set an event handler on the `RadDataForm`'s `Loaded` event, then call `RadDataForm.BeginEdit()` from that handler. That will put the form in edit mode once it loads.

```
<telerik:RadDataForm
    x:Name="ctrlPersonForm"
    AutoEdit="True"
    AutoGenerateFields="True"
    Header="Person"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=People}"
    Loaded="OnPersonFormLoaded">
</telerik:RadDataForm>

private void OnPersonFormLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ctrlPersonForm.BeginEdit();
}
```

If you just want to *insert* a new item when the control loads (as opposed to editing an existing item) then you can use that same handler to call the `RadDataForm.AddNewItem()` method:

```
private void OnPersonFormLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ctrlPersonForm.AddNewItem();
}
```

Comment: I set DataView to RadDataForm.ItemsSource. AddNewItem() method raised exception: "Cannot add external objects to this list."